# Opening an existing PDF in window form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Opening an existing PDF in window form in C#

Comment: https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package?q=pdf • https://www.google.com/search?q=github+winforms+display+pdf • `Process.Start("Document.pdf");`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it using custom event create event on form1 and hit event in form2

in form1 globe event

```
public event EventHandler OpenPDF;
```

add this code into form1 help button click event

```
if (OpenPDF!= null)
{
    this.OpenPDF(this, null);
}
```

and in form 2 initialize this event in constructor

```
var frm1= new form1();
frm1.OpenPDF+=delegate{
   axAcroPDF1.src = "File_name.pdf";
};
```

i think this is work